# How do I use magrittr::inset()?

Tags: r, magrittr

I understand that `magrittr::inset()` should be able to assign a vector to a new column in a dataframe (as a sort of opposite of `extract()`). But I don't understand how the syntax should work.

Say I've got, as a toy example:

```
df = data.frame( id = 1:26, letter = letters)
newvalue = rnorm(26)
```

I'd like to add newvalue as a new column to df within a magrittr chain. I'm assuming it's something like:

```
df %>%
  inset('new_column_name', newvalue)
```

But that doesn't work, presumably because I don't quite understand what the syntax for `[<-` (for which `inset()` is an alias) should look like.

Outside of a magrittr chain, I could do:

```
df['new_column_name']  <- newvalue
```

But my question is how to do it within a chain, where I've already done various and asundry operations.

Comment: `df %>% inset("this", value=LETTERS)`

Comment: I think maybe `df %>% inset(1:26,'new_column',LETTERS)` works.

Comment: `inset` is an alias for `[<-` And `[<-` is usually called with `var[arg1,arg2]<-arg3` which is equal to `"[<-"(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking your example vs my quick comment:

```
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame( id = 1:26, letter = letters)

newvalue <- rnorm(26)
```

Here's all you need to do:

```
df %>% inset("newvalue", value=newvalue)

##    id letter    newvalue
## 1   1      a -0.44805172
## 2   2      b -0.36284495
## 3   3      c  1.56175094
## 4   4      d  1.48775535
## 5   5      e -0.29086149
## 6   6      f  0.46456966
## 7   7      g  0.01130394
## 8   8      h  0.57100808
## 9   9      i -0.87445603
## 10 10      j  0.81932107
...
```

But, you can skip `magrittr`'s `inset()` altogether since this works:

```
`[<-`(df, "newvalue", value=newvalue)

##    id letter    newvalue
## 1   1      a -0.44805172
## 2   2      b -0.36284495
## 3   3      c  1.56175094
## 4   4      d  1.48775535
## 5   5      e -0.29086149
## 6   6      f  0.46456966
## 7   7      g  0.01130394
## 8   8      h  0.57100808
## 9   9      i -0.87445603
...
```

So does:

```
df %>% `[<-`("newvalue", value=newvalue)
```

Comment: Giving the same name (`newvalue`) to both vector and argument is confusing